# Сортировка столбцов таблицы: redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

У меня есть таблица, которую нужно отсортировать по разным параметрам (селектам и инпуту). Первый селект это выбор столбца по которому нужна сортировка, а второй селект, как сортировать столбцы. Я организовал сортировку по столбцам (убывание и возрастание).

Теперь мне нужно найти те элементы, которые либо соответствуют строке из инпута либо включают символы из него. Я немного запутался и не могу понять где организовать логику для работы с инпутом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот мой Reducer

```html
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_DATA':
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload,
                copyData: action.payload
            }
        case 'BY_FIELD_NAME':
            if (action.payload === 'name')
                return {
                    ...state,
                    byColumnName: action.payload,
                    data: [...state.data].sort(filterTable(action.payload, state.condition))
                };
            else if (action.payload === 'quantity')
                return {
                    ...state,
                    byColumnName: action.payload,
                    data: [...state.data].sort(filterTable(action.payload, state.condition))
                };
            else if (action.payload === 'distance')
                return {
                    ...state,
                    byColumnName: action.payload,
                    data: [...state.data].sort(filterTable(action.payload, state.condition))
                }; break;
        case 'MORE':
            return {
                ...state,
                condition: action.payload,
                data: [...state.data].sort(filterTable(state.byColumnName, action.payload)),
            }
        case 'LESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                condition: action.payload,
                data: [...state.data].sort(filterTable(state.byColumnName,     action.payload)),
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще тебе не нужны варианты `Равно` или `Содержит` во втором селекте. Тут правильнее было бы добавить чекбокс рядом с инпутом для варианта если нужно точнее совпадение. На изменение инпута и чекбокса добавить обработчик, передавать оба значения, redux:

Нужен второй массив, на основе отсортированного.

```
case 'FILTER':
    return {
         ...state,
         filteredData: state.data.filter(/* твоя логика тут */),
    }
```

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ